# Rails: Cannot set id for the what the object belongs_to during creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models but I am unable to set comment.post_id when creating it.

```
Post.rb
  has_many :comments
```

and

```
Comment.rb
  belongs_to :post
```

### Situation A (preferred):

The form for a new comment is on the post show page.
Therefore posts#show should finish with:

```
@comment = comment.new
@comment.post_id = params[:id]
```

and posts/show.html.erb should include:

```
<%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

However, the form throws a `Post can't be blank` error.

### Situation B:

The second thing I tried, which did not work, was this:

The post page links to a page for new comment and stores the post_id in the URL.

config/routes.rb includes:

```
get 'posts/:id/comment', to: 'comments#new', as: 'new_comment'
```

The link is formatted like so:

```
<%= link_to "New comment", new_comment_path(@post) %>
```

And comments#new contains

```
@review = Review.new
@review.player_id = params[:id]
```

This also does not work and the form returns `Post can't be blank`.

### Situation C

Same as B but post_id is stored in cookies like so...
posts#show includes:

```
@comment = Comment.new
session[:post_id] = params[:id]
```

posts/show.html.erb includes the link:

```
<%= link_to "new comment", new_comment_path %>
```

and comments#new is:

```
@review = Review.new
@review.player_id = session[:player_id]
session.delete(:player_id)
```

---

I originally thought the problem was the comment_params method, but it looks fine:

```
params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :post_id)
```

---

So how can I assign comment.post_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that after submitting the form, the form only sends back whatever fields it has. So even though the post_id is assigned, the comments#create action won't receive the value.

The solution is to create a hidden field in the form, like so:

```
<%= form.text_field :post_id, :hidden => true %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `comment belongs_to :post`, you need to deal with the Post, not the post_id. So:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = @post.comments.new
etc
```

Given what you've posted, it's not clear to me if the id of the post will be `params[:id]` or `params[:post_id]`, but I think you get the point.

Comment: `@comment = @post.comments.new` does the exact same thing as manually assigning `@comment.post_id` because that's the field that denotes the relationship